# yield() gives an incorrect mismatch error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I´ve defined six functions for a ETL process that I override in another file, each one returns a Map[String, Any] but the last one a Map[String, Unit], which is the insert into the target db. Is giving me an error when I execute it, that I don´t understand, in a yield() where I pass all the functions. The code is the following:

```
def genExtractParams(params: JObject, inputArray: Array[String]): 
Map[String, Any] = Map.empty[String, Any]

def extractData(exParams: Map[String, Any])(implicit spark: 
SparkSession): Map[String, Any] = Map.empty[String, Any]

def genTransformParams(params: JObject, exParams: Map[String, Any]): 
Map[String, Any] = Map.empty[String, Any]

def transformData(trParams: Map[String, Any], trDf: Map[String, Any]) 
(implicit spark: SparkSession): Map[String, Any] = Map.empty[String, Any]

def genLoadParams(params: JObject, inputArray: Array[String]): 
Map[String, Any] = Map.empty[String, Any]

def loadData(gParams: Map[String, Any], lParams: Map[String, Any]) 
(implicit spark: SparkSession): Map[String, Unit] = Map.empty[String, 
Unit]

def ETL(params: JObject, inputArray: Array[String])(implicit spark: 
SparkSession): Map[String,Unit] = {

   for {

       genEx:Map[String,Any]    <- genExtractParams(params, inputArray)
       extData:Map[String,Any]  <- extractData(genEx)
       genTr:Map[String,Any]    <- genTransformParams(params, extData)
       trData:Map[String,Any]   <- transformData(genTr, extData)
       genLd:Map[String,Any]    <- genLoadParams(params, inputArray)
       result: Map[String,Unit] <- loadData(genLd, trData)

   } yield result
 }
```

The error that gives me is the following:

```
found   : Map[String,Unit] => Map[String,Unit]
required: ((String, Unit)) => ?
    result: Map[String,Unit] <- loadData(genLd, trData)
                           ^
```

Any clue about why this happens? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by types, you shouldn't have any for-comprehension in the first place, it should be just

```
def ETL(params: JObject, inputArray: Array[String])(implicit spark: 
SparkSession): Map[String,Unit] = {    
   val genEx:Map[String,Any]    = genExtractParams(params, inputArray)
   val extData:Map[String,Any]  = extractData(genEx)
   val genTr:Map[String,Any]    = genTransformParams(params, extData)
   val trData:Map[String,Any]   = transformData(genTr, extData)
   val genLd:Map[String,Any]    = genLoadParams(params, inputArray)
   val result: Map[String,Unit] = loadData(genLd, trData)
   result
}
```

Your own code [translates into](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html)

```
genExtractParams(params, inputArray).flatMap { genEx: Map[String,Any] =>
  extractData(genEx).flatMap { extData => ...
```

which has wrong types in each line, the error you see just happens to be the one reported.